# Offline (unpowered) storage time limit for NAND based drives?

Tags: nand-flash

What's the storage time limit for NAND based drives?  Like Samsung EVO 850 or something similar?

Also, since USB storage drives use NAND flash... what's the storage limit on them as well?

When I ask about the time limit, I'm asking how long can the drive remain unpowered and still contain valid data.  Consider storage of ZIP or other critical bit files, unlike images/pictures/videos etc. that tend to fail when bits flip.

EDIT: I'm trying to understand how long a NAND flash based device can effectively retain information before that information becomes lost due to the known issue of electron leakage from the core storage mechanism.

Comment: impossible to guess without all details

Comment: If I remember right, they're generally rated to retain data for a minimum of ten years.

Comment: OP, are you asking for the manufacturer guaranteed time, or for the physical limit of the technology? If you rephrase your question to clarify this, I think you will get better reception!

Comment: @VladimirCravero I'm asking somewhat generically what the average limit for the technology is.

Comment: @Hearth I don't believe that's the case for NAND flash due to leakage of the electrons from the "wells".  You might be thinking about magnetic storage, which I do know has a long storage retention.

Comment: @enorl76 Random chip on digikey, [datasheet](http://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/6858/MX30LF2G18AC,%203V,%202Gb,%20v1.4.pdf) says 10 years data retention (page six).

Comment: @Hearth you probably should promote your comment into an answer and I can check it off... if its not right somebody will correct it

Comment: @enorl76 There you go. Added a bit about SLC vs MLC technology too.

Comment: This question is simply off-topic here.  Your choices are to pursue it with the drive manufacturer, or pursue it with someone who has done some testing that somehow with arguably credibility predicts how a relatively new-to-market device will behave over a longer period of time than it has yet existed.

Comment: @enorl76 contact the manufacturer, it varies from device to device. Some devices have very low storage times (enterprise SSD's only have a few months, because they are supposed to be always on) . Some SSD's have backup batteries to refresh the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're generally specified for a minimum of ten years. [This chip](http://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/6858/MX30LF2G18AC,%203V,%202Gb,%20v1.4.pdf) in particular, which is just a random part I found through digikey, quotes ten years storage time minimum (see page 6):

[image: A section of the Macronix MX30LFxG18AC datasheet, advertising "High Reliability" and specifically "Data Retention: 10 years"]

Note that this is true of *single-level cell* devices, which store one bit in each floating gate. There are also *multi-level cell* flash memories, which store multiple bits per gate by using more than two possible voltages. As the separation between the meaningful levels decreases, I would expect that the data retention would worsen, but I was unable to find any datasheets of MLC devices that specified a minimum retention time.

Comment: This is a bit misleading for the asker, as pretty much all current mass market drives will be MLC not SLC.  Nothing here allows estimating the retention of the drives they are actually interested in.

Comment: @Chris I don't exactly know very much about this topic, I've just worked with discrete flash memory in a project before and remembered seeing the 10 year spec on it. I assumed, since digikey has far more SLC flash chips than MLC, that MLC was still a relatively uncommon technology. Perhaps that assumption was incorrect?

Comment: What you can buy on digikey in the way of flash memory ICs, and what goes in SSD's used in todays computers are *extremely* distinct.  The question really isn't on topic here, and you can't readily extrapolate an answer from the kinds of questions that would be on topic.

Comment: Oh yeah, and now that there's QLC the potential for bit shift probably makes retentions go from years to months.   I ran into a tomshardware question and somebody said JEDEC specs are for a few months for QLC (dont quote me on that)